# "Saving Document set as a template" getting problem

Tags: document-set

I created document set with some data and designed the welcome page of it. but after saving as a template when I used the template in other location of the site, I could not find welcome page at all. Anyone please let me know if there is any way of solving this issue

Comment: how you design it using sp designer or any custom solution?

Comment: I just used document set and design within the share Point limits, I means to say adding my own views in the document library. But in the new location, I can not find my views.